# Rigorous proof of the limit of $x^x$ as $x \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f:(0,2) \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^x$. Assume that $f$ has a limit at $0$ and find that limit.

Hint: Choose a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1} ^\infty$ converging to $0$ such that the limit of the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is easy to determine.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $x_n=e^{-n}$ and $\log f(x_n)=x_n\log(x_n)=-ne^{-n}$

Answer (score 0):

First notice that $x^x = e^{x\ln x} = e^{\ln x/(1/x)}$.

Then use L'Hopital's rule to find $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0}\dfrac{\ln x}{1/x}$.